# .net calendering engine

Tags: .net, calendar

Is there a good .Net Calendering Engine (standalone) available that provides support for events, recurring events, reminders, invitations etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try basing your own calendar on this [one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/MonthCalendar.aspx). It already supports lots of features so extending it should be easier then writting one from scratch.

Comment: yes @MadBoy this is a good example but I needed different functionality and had to write one from scratch but rather a crude one compared to this one.

Comment: If you ever get to write your own hopefully you will release it to public just like this guy did ;-)

Answer (score 0):

there is one in SharePoint that you can use through it's .NET API. A standalone one that can be integrated into any app i do not know of. On a second thought it might not be much of a hassle to write one from scratch (as a windows service perhaps).

Comment: Dear for that you need to host SharePoint (either MOSS or WSS) to use that.

Comment: I know :). That's why i mentioned writing one from scratch